# Nuget restore version conflict build error on VSTS

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore, azure-pipelines-build-task

Builds fine locally but getting following error on VSTS build server. Issue is clear but not able to resolve it.

```
018-07-18T19:41:24.6993903Z ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue. 
 webapi.admin -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions (>= 2.1.1) 
 webapi.admin -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions (= 2.1.0).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly setting the version attribute resolved it, changed:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`
to

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />`

More details here: https://github.com/aspnet/Universe/issues/1180#issuecomment-392180608

Answer (score 1):

Can you upgrade `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` to version 2.1.1?

Or just upgrade all your nuget references to the latest version? (2.1.2 for these)

As for building locally working, try cleaning, or create a fresh clone of the source control repo and see if that works.

Comment: Resolved using https://github.com/aspnet/Universe/issues/1180. Changed <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
to <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />
by adding version attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with these issues too but it was because I simply copied a deployment YAML file from somewhere else and did not use the proper tooling. After following this tutorial, it worked like a charm:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops

More specifically, I think using the dotnet restore to restore your packages might fix it:

```
steps:
- script: dotnet restore
```

Make sure to install the correct .NET Core SDK, too.

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  inputs:
    version: '2.1.300' # replace this value with the version that you need for your project
```